# Character replaced with boxes in edit view?

Tags: bug, editing

What is going on with [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/256208/gpu-vs-integrated-graphics-hardware-browser-canvas-fingerprinting-and-multi-o)? It looks fine when viewing, but the text in the edit box is... a bit strange. Is this a bug, or has the user engaged in some kind of unicode shenanigans? A small sample of other questions all look normal to me when I try to edit them. This question also looks normal when I try to edit it on my phone instead of my laptop.

[image: Edit box of question with character replaced by boxes.]

**Update:** After the question has been edited, it now looks allright on my computer again. Very strange.

For the record, I am running Firefox 93.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: That's odd - I cannot replicate this. It looks normal in my edit box (Chrome on Windows)

Comment: @RoryAlsop Strange. It now looks right for me too.